# Foreach with condition on a specific attribute?

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach, indexing

I have a database where I store publications:
publication ID, Authors (priority is considered) and Publication title

I am having trouble with the second foreach as I need a loop to generate authors' names before moving to the title. the query will bring the result fine like:

PID Authors TITLE

1   NAME1 TITLE1

1   NAME2 TITLE1

1   NAME3 TITLE1

2   NAME1 TITLE2

2   NAME2 TITLE2

2   NAME3 TITLE2

and so on

I want the end result to be:

1 NAME1, NAME2, NAME3 TITLE1

2 NAME1, NAME2, NAME3 TITLE2

here is my code:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
    echo $row->PID;
    echo ": ";

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
      {
        echo $row->AUTHORS;
        echo ", ";
      }

    echo $row->TITLE;
    echo "<br>" . "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Why are you doing 2 foreach loops? And doesnt echo $row->PID</span>; break? Shouldnt it be echo $row->PID."</span>";

Comment: Because for each publication there are multiple authors. See the example I have provided. I need the second  foreach to generate author names before I can type the title and the start with the next publication and so on so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT() function when retrieve data from your database instead of using two for loops.For example you can use

SELECT PID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Authors SEPARATOR ','),TITLE1 FROM table GROUP BY PID;

Comment: How can I echo authors in my view. I tried { echo $row->authors; } but it says "Undefined property: stdClass::$authors". BTW, What a useful function, thank you very much.

Comment: Never mind just used GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Authors SEPARATOR ',') AS authors. it works, thank you again

Comment: Is there any way that I can have 'and' before the last name instead of commas ',' all the way??

Comment: Sorry you can't add like that only for last name.

Answer (score 0):

You used $query->result() on both query , try this

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->PID."</span>";
   echo ": ";

   echo implode(', ', $row->authors);

   echo $row->TITLE</span>;
   echo "<br>" . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I know that i used the same foreach, because i did not know how to specify the current row. I am away from my desktop, your answer sounds logically so thank you very much. I will try it once I am home. However, based on the example I have given above, the first 3 rows have the same PID and title only Position(names) is different. How can i make the second foreach bring names only with the same PID?

Comment: I suggest you just recode your query `select * from table order by PID, Priority`

Comment: It did not work, I think we still need the second loop to generate the names. I missed typed the example above (query result) and it was confusing, please read it as I just fixed it. Sorry about that. It should make sense now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.